# JAX-WS, @XmlJavaTypeAdapter, and a custom enum

Tags: java, soap, enums, jaxb, jax-ws

I am using a library that generates code based on IDL definitions.  Its great to be able to use common enumerations in various languages (Java, C and C++), but these generated enums don't seem to play well with JAX-WS.

Basically, main enum 'super' class has two members:  ordinal and name.  It looks similar to this  (Note: this is in a third party library and is not JavaBean friendly) :

```
public class CustomEnum {

    int _ordinal;
    String _name;

    public CustomEnum(int ordinal, String name) {
        this._ordinal = ordinal;
        this._name = name;
    }


    public int ordinal() {
        return _ordinal;
    }

    public String name() {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

So then in the generated code based on an IDL definition looks similar to this  (Using Day as an example -- but in actuality I have about 50 'enums' that extend CustomEnum, so I'd like a solution that keeps me from having multiple copies of enums around such as an IDL generated type and a java.lang.enum):

```
public class Day extends CustomEnum {

    public static final Day Sunday = new Day(0, "Sunday");
    public static final Day Monday = new Day(1, "Monday");
    public static final Day Tuesday = new Day(2, "Tuesday");
    public static final Day Wednesday = new Day(3, "Wednesday");
    public static final Day Thursday = new Day(4, "Thursday");
    public static final Day Friday = new Day(5, "Friday");
    public static final Day Saturday = new Day(6, "Saturday");

    public Day(int ordinal, String name) {
        super(ordinal, name);
    }
}
```

Note that I also do not want to mess with/rearrange/annotate this class either since it is generated code.

So, now what I want to do is to be able to use this 'Day' enum as a @WebParam in a JAX-WS @WebMethod.  Here is a very simple example of what I want to be able to do:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

    @WebService
    public class EnumEndpoint {

        @WebMethod
        public boolean callEndpoint(
                @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomEnumAdapter.class) Day day) {
            System.out.println(day.ordinal() + " " + day.name());
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I was hoping by writing an XmlJavaTypeAdapter like so:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class CustomEnumAdapter extends XmlAdapter<CustomEnum, EnumBean>
        implements Type {

    @Override
    public EnumBean unmarshal(CustomEnum v) throws Exception {
        EnumBean mine = new EnumBean(v.ordinal(), v.name());
        return mine;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomEnum marshal(EnumBean v) throws Exception {
        CustomEnum customEnum = new CustomEnum(v.getOrdinal(),v.getName());
        return customEnum;
    }

}
```

where EnumBean looks like:

```
public class EnumBean {

    int ordinal;
    String name;

    public EnumBean(int ordinal, String name) {
        this.ordinal = ordinal;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getOrdinal() {
        return ordinal;
    }

    public void setOrdinal(int ordinal) {
        this.ordinal = ordinal;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

but when I declare a Server Endpoint like this:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class Server {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:7979/enum", new EnumEndpoint());

    }

}
```

I get this error:

```
Jun 10, 2012 3:29:21 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getRequestWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating request wrapper Class test.jaxws.CallEndpoint
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value class test.CustomEnumAdapter
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.WrapperBeanGenerator.createRequestWrapperBean(WrapperBeanGenerator.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getRequestWrapperClass(RuntimeModeler.java:280)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:674)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:612)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:401)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:240)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:312)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:456)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:475)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:102)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:170)
    at test.Server.main(Server.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value class test.CustomEnumAdapter
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.newConstItem(ClassWriter.java:893)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.org.objectweb.asm.AnnotationWriter.visit(AnnotationWriter.java:185)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.WrapperBeanGenerator.createBeanImage(WrapperBeanGenerator.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.WrapperBeanGenerator.createRequestWrapperBean(WrapperBeanGenerator.java:245)
    ... 14 more
```

What am I missing here?  I tried to use 'Day' directly, but since it doesn't have a default constructor and is not get/set friendly, that doesn't work either.  Any tips?

Comment: Is my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11090763/383861) along the lines of what you are looking for?  If not please let me know I can help further.  I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead, so hopefully I can help you find a solution that works.

Comment: I apologize, I have been away from my desk for the past 2 days.  I will look closer at your solution this evening.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EnumBean**

If `EnumBean` is the adapted class then it needs to have a default constructor.

```
package forum10972195;

public class EnumBean {

    int ordinal;
    String name;

    public EnumBean() {

    }

    public EnumBean(int ordinal, String name) {
        this.ordinal = ordinal;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getOrdinal() {
        return ordinal;
    }

    public void setOrdinal(int ordinal) {
        this.ordinal = ordinal;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**CustomEnumAdapter**

Also the adapted class should appear as the first parameter when extending `XmlAdapter`.  Since the parameter you are mapping to is of type `Day` you are going to need to have the `XmlAdapter` specify `Day` as the bound type.

```
package forum10972195;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class CustomEnumAdapter extends XmlAdapter<EnumBean, Day> {

    @Override
    public EnumBean marshal(Day v) throws Exception {
        EnumBean mine = new EnumBean(v.ordinal(), v.name());
        return mine;
    }

    @Override
    public Day unmarshal(EnumBean v) throws Exception {
        Day day = new Day(v.getOrdinal(),v.getName());
        return day;
    }

}
```

---

**TEST CLIENT**

With the changes I suggested, I ran your service in WebLogic 12.1.1 and with the built in test client I got the following:

**Service Request**

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header />
    <env:Body>
    <callEndpoint xmlns="http://forum10972195/">
      <!--Optional:-->
      <arg0 xmlns="">
        <!--Optional:-->
        <name>string</name>
        <ordinal>3</ordinal>
      </arg0>
    </callEndpoint>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**Service Response**

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
    <ns0:callEndpointResponse xmlns:ns0="http://forum10972195/">
      <return>false</return>
    </ns0:callEndpointResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it is failing at runtime because of @XmlJavaTypeAdapter  annotation on your webmethod parameter - how about wrapping up your request parameter `Day` and your boolean response in wrapper message types, in your request wrapper, just declare it as `@XmlRootElement` and also declare your adapter `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomEnumAdapter.class)` . This way your @Webservice declaration does not have the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation.

Comment: I kind of get what you are saying... So XmlJavaTypeAdapter won't work directly on the WebMethod?

Comment: You can have the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on the parameter of a WebMethod as is given in the question.